# MySQL query data returns null GraphQL node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, graphql

I'm having trouble handling MySQL query data in the resolve function of GraphQL objects. The data returns null in GraphiQL despite printing with console.log(). I've tried using JSON.parse().

I have the following code:

Schema.js

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const queries = require('../mysql/queries');

const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLFloat,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLNonNull
} = graphql;

const AccountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Account',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        phone: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString }
    })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        account: {
            type: AccountType,
            args: { 
                email: { type: GraphQLString },
                password: { type: GraphQLString }
            },
            async resolve(parent, args) {
                return await queries.login(args.email, args.password);
            }
        }


module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
})
```

queries.js

```
var connection = require('./connection');
var db = connection.connect();

module.exports = {
    login: (email, password) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            var account = `SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE email="${email}" AND password="${password}"`;
            db.query(account, (err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (isEmpty(result[0])) return resolve(null);
                else return resolve(result);
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The function login in queries.js needs to return resolve(result[0]) as the AccountType object is not a GraphQLList.